# Why was my SuperUser post about video games closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, video-games

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are video game questions appropriate for superuser?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6542/are-video-game-questions-appropriate-for-superuser)

Why was this SuperUser [post](https://superuser.com/questions/2109/must-have) about video games closed?

I feel video games *are* software and that this post should be reopened.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15908/any-plans-for-a-videogame-console-related-site

Comment: @TheTXI: Why do you hate the English language so much that you would roll an edit back to horrible grammar and argumentative language?

Comment: assuming SuperUser _did_ allow questions on video games, "Must have" questions are also frowned upon.

Comment: @Rich B: Why do always edit out the original posters meaning and tone.  This is completely inapropriate, just stick to grammar and spelling.

Comment: @Lance: If you feel abuse has taken place, inform the moderators.

Comment: I was about to ask why is this a wiki, then I saw the 15 revisions. ;)

Comment: @Lance: Honestly, while editing other people's posts is always a bit controversial, I'm not sure Rich B did anything wrong here...he cleaned up the language mistakes and kept the jist of the question while making it much more likely to gain useful responses. Certainly, whether you agree with the practice in general, the intent here seems to have been good.  (Of course, ironically, he voted to close it after that...but I can't really argue with that either.)  While I don't like to modify tone myself, I don't think there's a set policy on it, so saying it's inapropriate is perhaps overstated.

Comment: @beska: Editing tone is appropriate when the OP's tone was inappropriate.

Answer (score 5):

The question is not if Video Game is software, but that Video Games are not considered to be appropriate on SuperUser as [stated in the FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq):

"Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about ...

- computer hardware
- computer software

… and it is not about videogames or consoles, then you're in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: game-related uilities and tools such as map editor are not games right?

Answer (score 4):

It was ruled very early on in SuperUser's beta period that questions concerning games are not acceptable questions.

If this is not to your liking, you can take it up further with Jeff Atwood & Co. at team@superuser.com. I should note, however, that Jeff was the one who first started bringing the hammer down.